# possibleFatalAuthenticationFailure flag - ignored by AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream-binder

Spring-AMQP added the possibleFailureAuthentication flag via [AMQP-750](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/commit/444ac6a38aa4f64906ac8e112282ac33919969de).  However, there is at least one case where the container can receive an AuthenticationFailureException and throw a FatalListenerStartupException, without checking that possibleFailureAuthentication flag (see [lines 630-633 in BlockingQueueConsumer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blame/v3.1.1/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/BlockingQueueConsumer.java#L630)).

Is this an intended case?  Whether or not it is, is there some way to end-run or catch and restart my container?  In my environment, I'm making use of RabbitMQ's [topology operator](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-topology-operator.html), so there can definitely be some timing deltas between Rabbit being up, services coming up, and users / vhosts / queues / exchanges all being set up.  My next intended attempt is to test using the DirectMessageListenerContainer rather than the SimpleMessageListenerContainer.

Stack trace below, demonstrating use of spring-amqp 3.1.1 (via Spring Boot 3.2.2 and Spring Cloud Stream)

> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.FatalListenerStartupException:
> Authentication failure    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:632)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1436)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1277)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na] Caused by:
> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpAuthenticationException:
> com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED -
> Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details
> see the broker logfile.   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:64)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:606)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:727)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:257)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$RabbitResourceFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:345)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:140)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:102)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:85)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:626)
> ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  ... 3 common frames omitted Caused
> by: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED
>
> - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:395)
>   ~[amqp-client-5.19.0.jar:5.19.0]  at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1251)
>   ~[amqp-client-5.19.0.jar:5.19.0]  at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1198)
>   ~[amqp-client-5.19.0.jar:5.19.0]  at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:652)
>   ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:621)
>   ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:568)
>   ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]  ... 10 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

The `BlockingQueueConsumer.start()` is called from the `AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize()` where we have a logic like:

```
        catch (FatalListenerStartupException ex) {
            if (isPossibleAuthenticationFailureFatal()) {
                throw ex;
            }
            else {
                Throwable possibleAuthException = ex.getCause().getCause();
                if (!(possibleAuthException instanceof PossibleAuthenticationFailureException)) {
                    throw ex;
                }
                else {
                    this.start.countDown();
                    handleStartupFailure(this.consumer.getBackOffExecution());
                    throw possibleAuthException;
                }
            }
        }
```

According to your stack trace we really in that situation.
Not sure what you think is wrong.

Comment: BlockingQueueConsumer isn't throwing a Fatal wrapping a PossibleAuthenticationFailure, it's throwing a Fatal which wraps a AmqpAuthenticationException, which then causes a throw again of Fatal, yes?  Were BlockingQueueConsumer to throw an AuthenticationFailureException, it would be a subclass of PossibleAuthenticationFailure, but I don't believe AmqpAuthenticationException is.

Comment: The `AmqpAuthenticationException` is thrown from the `RabbitExceptionTranslator` where it is wrapping the mentioned `PossibleAuthenticationFailureException`. That is confirmed by your stack trace. And then pay attention to the `ex.getCause().getCause()`. According to our stack it is exactly what you are mentioning: `FatalListenerStartupException <- AmqpAuthenticationException <- PossibleAuthenticationFailureException`. Your stack trace also confirms that there is a `RabbitExceptionTranslator` involved. So, what do I miss?

Comment: Sounds like I've missed something.  Given your feedback, my presumption is that I've missed setting the flag correctly.  My path of using the DirectMessageListenerContainer was avoiding the exception yesterday, so I'll hold that in reserve as a possible path forward.

Comment: So, are we good? Or do you have more arguments to prove that something is off in the library?

Comment: It'll take me a bit to reproduce with the flag - will close the question, etc, once I've proven that out: expect to resolve sometime this morning.  Appreciate the back and forth.

Comment: Following up: I am not able to cause the flag to have any change in behavior.  I have tried the following approaches:

* set SPRING_AMQP_GLOBAL_PROPERTIES_MLC_POSSIBLE_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE_FATAL: "false" across all containers.  (Also verified that the corresponding missingQueuesFatal property is not set)

* added a ListenerContainerCustomizer bean: verified the bean exists, but its configure method apparently never gets called (no change in behavior, no execution of the log message I embedded in it)

* added a ContainerCustomizer (amq.rabbit.config) bean

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. Doesn't look like this is related somehow to the code we are talking about. If you believe there is a problem in Spring AMQP, please, try to isolate it into a simple Spring project. There is no need in Kubernates to prove that something is off in the library.

Comment: Oh, believe me, I appreciate the challenge of wading this through the various layers of projects in Spring.   I am poking at the problem through docker-compose (so I have a true Rabbit binder interaction), as well through k8s.  Your earlier comments indicated that the likely problem was the possibleAuthenticationFailureFatal flag wasn't being set.  It appears you're right, and so I tried to do so given Spring Boot + Spring Cloud Stream, working with a Rabbit binder.  Maybe someone will have proof code: hunts on GH in spring-projects haven't worked.  Thanks, though

Comment: There is no such a property `SPRING_AMQP_GLOBAL_PROPERTIES_MLC_POSSIBLE_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE_FATAL` processed anywhere in the Spring AMQP. The docs only talks about `spring.amqp.global.properties` bean of the `Properties` instance which may have an entry like `mlc.possible.authentication.failure.fatal = false`. But what is showing through env var is not handled in Spring AMQP.